# present perfect for along time ago

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> 1. They have been working together recently.
> 2. They have been working together for a long time.

And which one is correct here?

> 1. They have been good friends recently.
> 2. They have been good friends for a long time.

Comment: As long as they're still working together now (or still friends) they're ***all*** correct. Why do you think  some of them are wrong?

Comment: 'They have been good friends recently' doesn't sound idiomatic to me; I'd prefer a 'since occasion O1 / year T1' or 'for about X1 months'. Or 'until quite recently' if they're not now good friends.

Comment: Note that had you added 'ago,' i.e. "They have been good friends for a long time *ago*," it would be incorrect. (Just commenting as in the title you have 'a long time ago').  The addition of that single word would make it incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Grammar-wise, they're all correct. It would depend on what you're trying to say. Each sentence could have a slightly different meaning...

The "recently" sentences don't let the audience know how long they have been friends or worked together. All we know is that it has been recently.

The "long time" sentences let us know that these relationships have been continuing on for a while. Even though you don't say "recently" in these, it *could* be implied. It depends on how the reader takes it.